# Sending a transaction fails

Tags: ethereum

I am using web3.js v1.0 with solidity ^0.4.17 with Ganache v1.1.0. I am trying to call a send transaction and it fails with the error message below.

> Returned error: Error: Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs
>   from RPC 'undefined' for method 'sendRawTransaction' Error:
>   [ethjs-format] hex string 'undefined' must be an alphanumeric 66 utf8
>   byte hex (chars: a-fA-F) string, is 0 bytes

*MyContract.sol*

```
  function createStarCard(string name, uint price) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner);

    uint starCardId = starCards.push(StarCard(name, price));
    starCardIdToOwner[starCardId] = owner;
  }
```

*App.js*

```
  createStarCard = ({ name, price }) => {
    window.web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => {
      this.state.ContractInstance.methods.createStarCard(name, price).send({
        from: accounts[0],
        gas: 300000,
      }).then((receipt) => {
        console.log(receipt)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message) <-- Caught error message
      })
    })
  }
```

Google search results with the error message pointed me to the following issues, but they weren't helpful in my case:

- https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/1870
- https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23679/callback-contain-no-result-error-error-ethjs-query-while-formatting-outputs

*Update: sharing my constructor for App.js*

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
      this.web3Provider = window.web3.currentProvider;
    } else {
      console.log("Use Ganache web3")
      this.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
    }

    window.web3 = new Web3(this.web3Provider);

    const contractAddress = "0x1bdaf0cd259887258bc13a92c0a6da92698644c0"
    const ContractInstance = new window.web3.eth.Contract(Abi, contractAddress);

    this.state = {
      ContractInstance,
    }
  }
```

Comment: How do you create `this.state.ContractInstance`? What does `this.state.ContractInstance.address` return?

Comment: @gaiazov I updated the question with the information. It has `_address` property instead of `address` and the value is the contract's address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the Ganache mac app. I solved this by using `ganache-cli` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by reinstalling Metamask.